# use google to search in a url

Tags: javascript, textinput, google-search

I want to use Google to search in my URL. I want to use these code:

```
site: http://my-url.ir/ my_words_that_want_to_search
```

then I have a text input and a button for search

I want HTML(or JavaScript) that when I click on the button put text that is in text input in

```
site: http://my-url.ir/ text_that_is_in_text_input
```

Comment: i dont think its possible if yes then how will you show the result ?

Comment: @Mayankswami I think he mean more like redirect to google itself with the keywords but filtering to his `site:`, just like [w3 org](http://www.w3.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Google Custom Search Engine](http://www.google.com/cse/), which will create such code snippets for you.

According to [this query string anatomy](http://www.blueglass.com/blog/google-search-url-parameters-query-string-anatomy/), you can just add another parameter instead of adding `site:xyz` to the search string:

```
<form method="GET" action="//www.google.de/search">
    <input type="hidden" name="as_sitesearch" value="http://example.com">
    <input type="text" name="q">
    <input type="submit" value="Search!">
</form>
```

No need to use JavaScript for a simple search form.